# Caracteres utf-8 são substituídos por "▒" no git bash

Tags: python, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Quando eu executo meu código python, se nesse código tiver um print, e esse print receber uma string com caracteres utf-8, a letra é trocada por ▒ no console.

**código:**
`print('Olá')`

**output**
`ol▒`

Answer (score -1):

tenta colocar `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` no começo do código, isso meio que força a codifição para utf-8 no Python.

Comment: esa prática não é uma "fórmula mágica para resolver todos os problemas de acentuação". em particular, se o problema fosse esse, a A.P. teria um "Erro de sintaxe", e o programa nem seria executado.